Where do I put the password for a Windows install on an old external hard drive?
I have an external hard drive that is most likely Windows 8 and my current laptop is Windows 10.
I'm able to connect to it with an adapter but whenever I get to the password protected folder (users), it says I don't have permission without asking for a password.
I have the password, I just don't know where go to unlock it.

Clicking continue doesn't do anything.

It's likely referring to ACLs - take ownership of the HDD's drive letter, apply the changes recursively, then add your user with full access permissions, applying the changes recursively

A screenshot would be helpful

How do you have the password without knowing what's on the hard drive?

@JW0914 I wish I knew what that meant lol. I'm sure I just need to enter my password somewhere

@Ramhound added. I get that message after double clicking on the users folder

@JaromandaX The hard drive is from my old laptop that doesn't work. If I could boot straight to the hard drive I would just login to it. For now I just wanna access my old files but im never prompted to put a password for it.

You need to take ownership of the folder. This will permanently prevent being able to access the user. The prompt you receive suggests no user on the system your accessing the drive has any permissions to the folder.


This is an Access Control [ACL] error and nothing to do with any encryption - to resolve:

GUI:

Explorer: Right-click folder → Properties → Security → Advanced

Owner: Change → Select a principal → Enter username → OK
Permission Entries: Set username to Full Control

Add → Select a principal → Enter username → OK
Tick: Full Control




OK → OK 


CLI:

Open an Admin terminal: +R → Open: powershell → Ctrl+Shit+OK

# If not using PowerShell, change ${env:UserName} to %UserName%

# Set Ownership to user (Z: external HDD):
  TakeOwn /F "Z:\Path\to\Folder" /R

# Add user with Full Control permissions:
  Icacls "Z:\Path\to\Folder" /c /t /Grant:r ${env:UserName}:F /Inheritance:e

Icacls | TakeOwn




I used the command line option  but was given "ERROR: Access is denied." I'm not really trying to do anything complicated. My old laptop (the place I got the external HD from) is password protected. I have the password, I just dont know where to use it. I've tried to boot from the external so I can login but apparently going to the bios isn't enough and i'm missing whatever steps.

@hardwarepc1157 For which command? Repeat step 1, except this time hold down Ctrl+Shift while clicking OK, which will open an Admin terminal

I tried the two answers given and the result was what appears to be a total loss of data in the folder ("Documents and Settings") I tried to set the principal for. It appears it was overwritten with a link to the current computers folder of the same name.
I have the feeling that the mentioned solutions are on the edge of being potentially very harmful and it should be stated somewhere that messing things up (eg, trying both solutions not just one), can lead to data loss.

@Creech It's literally impossible for changing ACLs via the GUI/CLI to result in lost data - both are the correct way to fix the error message within your question (I also linked to the man pages within this answer I'd encourage reading). There appears to be a fundamental misunderstanding of what the problem is - please edit your question with additional information to provide clarity for what the issue is. Perhaps screenshot every single step you take, starting with Explorer when plugging the drive in. Please also paste the output of the following into a code box: icacls Z:/Path/to/Folder
